# Force wait for NSURLSessionDataTask completion

Tags: objective-c, wait, nsurlsessiontask

I'm making a `URLRequest` that sends attempted login information and waits for a response from the web service to find out if the user can/cannot log in.

The way I was hoping to do this was by having the user type in his **username & password** into two text fields and then press a button, which would call the function below.  This function would start an `NSURLSessionDataTask` and construct a struct with the boolean **success/failure** of the login and an `NSString` with the corresponding error message (if any).

The problem is that my function returns the struct before my `NSURLSessionDataTask's` completion block has finished executing.  Is there a way for me to force my program to wait until this task either times out or completes?  Alternatively, can I push execution of the completion block onto the main thread & before the function returns?

Thanks!  Please let me know if there are any clarifications I need to make!

(Also, I have seen some similar questions circulating around StackOverflow that mention GCD.  Is this an overkill solution?  None of those questions seem to be talking about quite the same thing, or do so on a level that is higher than my current understanding.  I am still very new to Objective-C)

```
- (struct RequestReport) sendLoginRequest: (NSString*) username withPassword:  (NSString *) password
```

... (creating the request & setting HTTP body)

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:0 error:nil];

    success = (BOOL)jsonObject[@"success"];
    statusText = (NSString *) jsonObject[@"errors"];

}];

[dataTask resume];

struct RequestReport rr;
rr.status = statusText;
rr.success = success;

return rr;
```

Comment: The typical design pattern for this type of problem is to pass a callback block that is executed when the task returns and show a loading indicator in the mean time. The method should be void, and the callback block executed in the callback from the NSURLSessionDataTask.

Comment: Aw, I hate having to write more methods :P  I was hoping there was another solution, especially since my program does effectively have to "block" until the user is logged in.  For security reasons, there are no features available to non-logged users.

Comment: Oh wait, you're not saying to write another method.  A callback block?  So like, passing in a delegate function (not sure what it's called in Objective-c) as a parameter to the login function?

Comment: That is the typical situation for most apps on the app store. If you are new to networks calls on iOS, I highly recommend you use AFNetworking or another 3rd party framework to do most of the legwork for you, or better yet the Parse SDK if you are using Parse for your backend. I very rarely write my own networking code since there are such great open-source solutions out there.

Comment: A block is not technically a method its just a chunk of code that can be moved around by a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method should look like this:

```
- (void) sendLoginRequest:(NSString*) username withPassword:(NSString *) password callback:(void (^)(NSError *error, BOOL success))callback
    {
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            // Handle error
        }
        else {
           callback(error, YES);
       }
  }];

    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Call this method like so:

```
[self sendLoginRequest:@"myUsername" password:@"password" callback:^(NSString *error, BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
         NSLog(@"My response back from the server after an unknown amount of time";
    }
}
```

See [Apple's Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/programmingwithobjectivec/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) for more reading on blocks and [fuckingblocksyntax.com](http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/) for how to declare blocks.

Comment: Thanks; I've been thinking about this in completely the wrong way.  I'll look into callbacks.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the syntax here.

Comment: (oops, I did not mean to press enter.)
(void(^)(NSArray *objects))callback
^ what is the NSArray *objects?

Comment: Thanks!  This solves my problem :)  woohoo!  I learned something new today!